# Xpath for a div specifying a class and just one style attribute

Tags: xpath

I want to write an xpath to identify a div which has the class foo and the display: block. I wrote

```
div[@class="foo" and @style="*display: block*"]
```

but it doesn't work. Is it correct to use and? is it correct to use asterisks like in regex expressions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

your xpath is searching for `@style="*display: block*"`, it means totally equal to value inside quotes. Use `contains()` instead, 
Fyi: there's also `starts-with()` method

```
//div[@class='foo'][contains(@style,'display: block')]
```

There's an issue with using such locator, as sometimes element is visible, though there's no style `display:block`. So you can use similar locator, but instead of containing block, searche for not-containing "none" (as in display:none), can try it by adding this to main locator `[not(contains(@style, 'none'))]`. Just remember about such option)

Comment: Is there any difference to `//div[@class='foo' and contains(@style, 'display: block')]` ?

Comment: no) i just prefer not to use 'and' , as it's more text, but both are correct)

Comment: there's an issue with using such locator, as sometimes element is visible, though there's no style `block`. So once i used totally similar locator, but instead of containing `block` i searched for `not-containing "none"` (as in display:none), can try it by adding this to main locator `[not(contains(@style, 'none'))]`. Just remember about such option)

Comment: @VitaliyMoskalyuk: At least on a German keyboard ` and ` is way easier to type than square brackets (`Alt Gr` + `8`, `Alt Gr` + `9`). I believe that's one reason why some German programmers use English keyboards / keyboard layouts ;)